# Use Intellij File Watcher only on Open File

Tags: intellij-idea, go

I've been using the Intellij Golang plugin recently (it's great) but I've been running into an issue with the File Watchers I set up. My working directory is set to my `$GOPATH` directory and I would like to be able to run `golint` and `goimports` after I save a file I'm working on. The issue I have is if I use git to clone a repo the next time I open Intellij it runs both `golint` and `goimports` on all the newly imported files which can take a long time for large projects. Is there a way to set up File Watcher so it only watches a file that is currently open? I added a screenshot of my current settings below:

[image]

Comment: I don't know about the plugin, but there ought to be a way to point the plugin at a shell script that checks for an environment variable or dot file instead of the raw golint

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open `Watcher setting` -> `Scope` , change it to `Open Files`
[image]

If you wanna more control over the plugin, you can have a look at the [official doc](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/using-file-watchers.html)

Comment: I don't seem to have the `Open Files` option in the `Scope` drop-down menu under `Watcher Settings`. I'm using the Community Edition though, do you know if it's only available in the payed version? I checked the docs but didn't see any distinctions made between the two. I posted a screenshot of what the drop down looks to me to [AWS S3](https://s3.amazonaws.com/jeromefroe/Screen+Shot+2016-05-05+at+8.43.05+AM.png) if that helps. Thanks!

Comment: @JeromeFroelich I'm using the latest version of IDEA Community 2016.1 with File Watcher plugin 145.28, have no idea why you doesn't have this option.

Comment: that did! Thanks! I was using the 2015 edition, once I downloaded the 2016 edition the option appeared.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of file watcher you can get [External tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.1/external-tools.html?origin=old_help) configured to achieve almost the same functionality. The only difference is that this won't run on save but rather you'll have to trigger this manually. Or you could configure a macro to run them on save (but I don't have experience with macros + external tools so I'm not if this will work).

Comment: Thanks! I was able to make this work by creating an External Tool like you suggested and then mapping it to a Keyboard Shortcut. Now I can control when `go fmt`, `golint`, `goimports`, etc. are run. I'll have to try it out to see how I like it versus it being automatic when I save. I'm going to leave the answer open for now just to see if anyone has encountered the same problem with File Watchers and found a solution.